# Save data type JSONField from celery

Tags: json, django, rabbitmq, celery, celerybeat

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime 
from django.db.models import TextField, JSONField, Model
# Create your models here.
class reservation(models.Model):
    res=models.JSONField()
    da = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def ress():
content={
           "customer": 48,
               "reservation_id_pms": str(id),
               "reservation_channel_number": None,
               "reservation_group_id_pms": "ed2b9d55-46d9-4471-a1e9-ad6c00e30661",
               "extra_reservation_code": "550ca1c1",
               }
       reservations=reservation.objects.create(res=content)
       reservations.save()
       res.append(content)
   return None
```

error:

> from django.db.models import TextField, JSONField, Model ImportError:
> cannot import name 'JSONField' from 'django.db.models'
> (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/**init**.py)

Comment: Its most likely related to this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614542/6505847

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using lower versions of Django (< 1.9) when JSONField was not introduced. So try upgrading the version.

If this is not the case, then try installing simplejson library as sometimes the library may not come with Django itself.

```
pip install simplejson
```

Comment: thx but he does not work version django= 2.2.14

Comment: Can you provide your installed dependencies(requirements.txt file contents) by running command: pip freeze > requirements.txt